# Object Stretching When in Pose Mode

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

[image: stretch]

[image: weightpaint]

I rigged my first character and all looks good expect for the foot. When I move the spine bone, the heel of the foot stays on the ground while the rest of the model moves.

I thought it was an issue with weight painting so I selected the body, went into weigh paint mode, then selected the bone and went into pose mode. From there I could see what I thought was the issue so I weight painted it out.

It looks good to my eyes, see the screenshot, but I must still be missing something. Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Those bones below the feet, make sure they don't have any unwanted weight attached to them. Seems like the issue

Comment: Apart from the footbone which has weights, I checked the toes and those other bones. Really stumped on this. I see no other weights from other bones.

Answer (score 0):

The bone called *ik.leg.L* should not have its *Deform* option enabled, because it's a controller bone that is not supposed to deform the mesh. So disable this option:

[image]

The pixel is mainly part of the vertex group of the same name, remove it from all groups...

[image]

and assign it to the group called *foot1.L*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I thought I did this already but I either missed it or reverted back to an old save before I had done it.

Comment: Also maybe parent the foot bone to the controller?